# When to pronounce as [dz] and [dʑ] in Korean ㅈ (IPA)?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm looking at the [Korean IPA chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Korean) and found out the two symbols for ㅈ:

- dz    ㅈ   j   beds
- dʑ    ㅈ   j   roughly like gee

But what is the difference and when I should pronounce them over the other? I'm not exactly sure how I should pronounce the latter sound, but is it correct that the tongue position is slightly back in the mouth?

Comment: I'm not a linguist, but I feel that the wikipedia page is misleading - apparently its authors decided to add every possible phonetic variations ever encountered in any study, such as listing [z] under ㅅ (it doesn't sound right to me). Compare with English IPA chart, which would have been three times larger if one similarly listed all possible variations.

Comment: Here is not an answer, just saying : I'm pretty sure that no one(except linguist) in Korea can tell difference between two nor care about that.
And here is an (kind of) answer : According to [Korean Wikipedia article ㅈ](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%85%88), `[d͡z]`/`[t͡s⁽ʰ⁾]` is used in North Korea, and `[d͡ʑ]`/`[t͡ɕ⁽ʰ⁾]` is used in South Korea. I think answer below can be more accurate, so I just leave a comment. ... Also I'm not a linguist, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phoneme /dz/ is purely alveolar, whereas /dʑ/ is alveolo-*palatal*. The voiceless equivalents (and the more common IPA versions) are /ts/ and /tɕ/, as further explained [on that same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Korean).

The palatal consonants are pronounced [with the middle of the tongue (the body) raised toward the hard palate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_consonant). Hence it feels like more "middle of the mouth" than the pure alveolar or dental "front of the mouth" consonants.

The comparison to English *beds* /bɛdz/ and *gee* /dʒiː/ is not bad, as an approximation.

How does that work for ㅈ ? In the standard Seoul-based Korean, it is to do with what vowels follow it: /dz/ is the sound before the back vowels ㅏ, ㅓ; the more palatal version /dʑ/ is used for other vowels. In North Korean, /dz/ seems to be used before more of the vowels, and /dʑ/ only before the front vowel ㅣ and iotated vowels (ㅑ, ㅕ, ㅠ, etc.).

But this difference is not as strong for ㅈ, in contrast to ㅅ.

Compare 하자 (*haja*) with 하지 (*haji*). In the modern standard Seoul-based Korean pronunciation, both are somewhat palatal, although palatalisation is stronger (as in, the tongue goes further up/back) with the latter.

Now compare the difference in 도사 (*dosa*) with 도시 (*dosi*). The ㅅ sounds very different between the two: the first one is definitely an alveolar /s/, whilst the second one is an alveolo-palatal /ɕ/, closer to the English "sh".

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in voicing. If a sound is voiced, it means you can feel your voice box vibrate if you place your fingers there.

- /tɕ/ ㅈ is unvoiced. Always found at the beginning of a word, and sometimes in the middle.
- /dʑ/ ㅈ is voiced. Always found between vowels or voiced consonants and never at the beginning of a word.

The [Fluent Forever Korean pronunciation videos](https://blog.fluent-forever.com/korean-resources/#koreanvideo1) have native speaker examples and detailed linguistic explanations. You should study all four videos, but I'll highlight the parts relevant to this question:

- [Voicing and aspiration explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVqJbiSLw-E&t=313)
- [/tɕ/ ㅈ (unvoiced; lax)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVqJbiSLw-E&t=732)
- [/dʑ/ ㅈ (voiced)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S31_x00UoQ0&t=365)